# downloading multiple URLs at once (without blocking user interface, with progress reporting)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an Winform application that starts about 1000 web requests and processes the result. I'm using a BackgroundWorker right now, which loops over the URL list, requests them one after the other with a HTTPClient, processes the result and reports the progress with BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress to the user interface.

This works fine, but I'd like to speed this up by requesting multiple URLs at once. It still should report a progress and must not block the user interface. I could create threads and do all myself, but I'm quite sure that there is a better solution with charming .NET features. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can just do an Parallel.ForEach, which increment an atomic integer after each loop and update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Microsoft's Reactive Framework. It was designed for exactly this kind of thing.

Try this:

```
var urls = new []
{
    "http://www.microsoft.com",
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.apple.com"
};

var query =
    from url in urls.ToObservable()
    from html in Observable.Using(
        () => new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(),
        client => Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetStringAsync(url)))
    select new { url, html };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(
            result =>
            {
                /* Process each `result.url` & `result.html`
                   as they come in */
            },
            exception => { /* handle exception */ },
            () => { /* All done successfully */ });
```

It's all multi-threaded and async. Each `HttpClient` created is properly disposed and each result comes in as soon as possible. And the `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` can be replaced with `.ObserveOn(formInstance)` for WinForms and `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` for WPF so that you're handling the results on the UI thread.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" for the basic bits, and "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" for the WinForms bits, and "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading" for the WPF bits.